# HTML Table from Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Below I have the code for my HTML table that is created from an ajax request pulling SharePoint list items. In the screenshot it shows how it works and what it displays after the button is clicked. How do I get my table to load without having to click the button that way when I load the page it is already displayed?

Secondly, how can I get rid of the header rows when it pulls from the second list since the information data is pulled from lists with the same items. I would much rather have a column on the side showing which list the rows are from instead.

Any suggestions?

[Table in Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b6vG.png)

[AFter edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXEWn.png)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXEWn.png

```html
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btnClick" value="Get Employee Information" />
<div id="EmployeePanel">
  <table id='employeeTab' style="width: 100%;" border="1 px">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="employees" style="width: 100%"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btnClick").click(function() {
    var fullUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('EmployeeInfo')/items?$select=Title,Age,Position,Office,Education,Degree";
    var fullUrl1 = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee2')/items?$select=Title,Age,Position,Office,Education,Degree";
    $.ajax({
      url: fullUrl,
      type: "GET",
      headers: {
        "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
      },
      success: onSuccess,
      error: onError
    });
    
    $.ajax({
      url: fullUrl1,
      type: "GET",
      headers: {
        "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
      },
      success: onSuccess,
      error: onError
    });

    function onSuccess(data) {
      var objItems = data.d.results;
      var tableContent = '<table id="employeeTab" style="width:100%" border="1 px"><thead><tr><td><strong>Name</strong></td>' + '<td><strong>Age</strong></td>' + '<td><strong>Position</strong></td>' + '<td><strong>Office</strong></td>' + '<td><strong>Education</strong></td>' + '<td><strong>Degree</strong></td>' + '</tr></thead><tbody>';

      for (var i = 0; i < objItems.length; i++) {
        tableContent += '<tr>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Title + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Age + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Position + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Office + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Education + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Degree + '</td>';
        tableContent += '</tr>';
      }
      $('#employees').append(tableContent);
    }

    function onError(error) {
      alert('Error');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: use document ready ,  and trigger click, $("#btnClick").trigger('click') or make it a function instead of event, and call that

Comment: and second is because you are creating table again,  just add this html to your html , and use $('#employeeTab tbody').append(tableContent)   , here tableContent should only contain data rows which are in loop

Comment: @AhmedSunny would you mind demonstrating in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the table headers under table content, then append to the table.

```
var tableContent = '<table id="employeeTab" style="width:100%" border="1 px"><thead><tr><td><strong>Name</strong></td>' + '<td><strong>Age</strong></td>' + '<td><strong>Position</strong></td>' + '<td><strong>Office</strong></td>' + '<td><strong>Education</strong></td>' + '<td><strong>Degree</strong></td>' + '</tr></thead><tbody>';
    
          for (var i = 0; i < objItems.length; i++) {
            tableContent += '<tr>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Title + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Age + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Position + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Office + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Education + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Degree + '</td>';
            tableContent += '</tr>';
          }
          $('#employees').append(tableContent);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JS code must be on window's load listener, that means when the page gets loaded.

```js
$(function() {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var fullUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('EmployeeInfo')/items?$select=Title,Age,Position,Office,Education,Degree";
    var fullUrl1 = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee2')/items?$select=Title,Age,Position,Office,Education,Degree";
    var firstResp = [];
    $.ajax({
      url: fullUrl,
      type: "GET",
      headers: {
        "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
      },
      success: firstrequestHandler,
      error: onError
    });


    function firstrequestHandler(aFirstReqResponse) {
      firstResp = aFirstReqResponse;
      $.ajax({
        url: fullUrl1,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
          "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: onSuccess,
        error: onError
      });

    }

    function onSuccess(data) {
      data = firstResp.concat(data);
      var objItems = data.d.results;
      var tableContent = '<table id="employeeTab" style="width:100%" border="1 px"><thead><tr><td><strong>Name</strong></td>' + '<td><strong>Age</strong></td>' + '<td><strong>Position</strong></td>' + '<td><strong>Office</strong></td>' + '<td><strong>Education</strong></td>' + '<td><strong>Degree</strong></td>' + '</tr></thead><tbody>';

      for (var i = 0; i < objItems.length; i++) {
        tableContent += '<tr>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Title + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Age + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Position + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Office + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Education + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Degree + '</td>';
        tableContent += '</tr>';
      }
      $('#employees').append(tableContent);
    }

    function onError(error) {
      alert('Error');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Asutosh, that works crystal clear. Is there anyway you know how I can get the second list to append to the same table instead of making another table?

Comment: I have updated, basically merging both responses from respective calls and then rendering the table.

Comment: It yields a really messed up table, I will update my post and post a screenshot to let you see what it loads.

Comment: I added the picture with hyperlink [After Edit], it gave me that after I loaded it into the script editor, then I tried again and it yielded nothing there was no table at all.

Comment: Are both the calls returning similar response.

Comment: from the edit you tried? Or in general. Both calls are returning list data that contain the same items, just different sub-items (i.e. names ages... are all the same header, just have different inputs)

Comment: then it's a complex solution than what I was thinking of having two responses similarity in mind, if possible please create a JSfiddle where you can put some response data of these two calls.

Comment: the returns are the same, it is just from two different lists. I do not believe I can pull SharePoint list data to JSFiddle

Comment: any idea I feel like youre so close

Comment: Need to check both responses, else its difficult to predict.

Comment: both of the calls are returning similar responses

Comment: Also, singular table aside. How would I go about inserting a column showing what information is from what list on the side of the table.

Answer (score 1):

make table in your html

```
<input type="button" id="btnClick" onclick="load_table_function()" value="Get Employee Information" />

<div id="EmployeePanel">
    <div id="employees" style="width: 100%">
        <table id="employeeTab" style="width:100%" border="1 px">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Age</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Position</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Office</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Education</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Degree</strong></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

changes in js

```
     function load_table_function() {
         var fullUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('EmployeeInfo')/items?$select=Title,Age,Position,Office,Education,Degree";
    var fullUrl1 = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee2')/items?$select=Title,Age,Position,Office,Education,Degree";
    $.ajax({
      url: fullUrl,
      type: "GET",
      headers: {
        "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
      },
      success: onSuccess,
      error: onError
    });

    $.ajax({
      url: fullUrl1,
      type: "GET",
      headers: {
        "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
      },
      success: onSuccess,
      error: onError
    });
    function onSuccess(data) {
      var objItems = data.d.results;
      var tableContent = '';
      
      for (var i = 0; i < objItems.length; i++) {
        tableContent += '<tr>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Title + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Age + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Position + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Office + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Education + '</td>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + objItems[i].Degree + '</td>';
        tableContent += '</tr>';
      }
      $('#employeeTab tbody').append(tableContent);
    }
}
```

and for on load

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   load_table_function();
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing this, and all it displays is the button (Which I have finally gotten rid of and added the event listener 'load'), and the table headers but does not populate the body.

Comment: Any idea why it is doing that?

Comment: do a console.log(tableContent)  before append line, see if it contains anything, it should work, or try .html(tableContent)  instead of append , see if that works or not

Comment: Ive run into the issue quite a bit, I used console.Log but I am unable to find where it logs to or if it even logs. I open developer tools and it never shows anything relative.

Comment: in developertools (f12 to open)  click on console tab, and see if logs are active, you will notice buttons on the side, on chrome, its  on  right sde with  box and and right angle